# LoadedPivotItem event on Pivot control not fired first time, WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, pivot

is there any reason why event LoadedPivotItem is not fired when DataContext of Pivot is being assigned therefore creating Pivot Items ?

It is only fired when I swype to next pivot item which is already handled by _SelectionChanged event.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo
    (System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var someData = LoadData();

        pivot.DataContext = someData;
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

 void pivot_LoadedPivotItem(object sender, PivotItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Will not stop here after data being assigned to DataContext
    }
```

I need this event in particular cause I need PivotItem and it's data context for further operations.
Is there something I am doing wrong, or is there some other event that I can use here while getting a PivotItem ( PivotItemEventArgs ).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the timing of how your page is loading. I don't see you attaching an event handler in your code, so I'm assuming that you're specifying the event handler in your XAML. The event may be firing too early, before everything on your page is fully loaded and wired up.

Try removing the event handler from your XAML and moving it to your `OnNavigatedTo` event (pseudocode):

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo (NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var someData = LoadData();

    pivot.DataContext = someData;
    OnLoadedPivotItem += pivot_LoadedPivotItem;
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

If that doesn't work, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/10/24/loaded-event-timing-in-silverlight.aspx) might be helpful. It describes the sequence of events that happens as the control tree is loaded. The suggestion that jumped out as potentially useful was attaching to the `LayoutUpdated` event instead of the `Loaded` event.